# constructing an if statement in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to build an if statement equivalent to:

```
If([some table:field] contains string [another table:field]) 
  show [another table:field] 
else iterate through the values in [another table])
```

I am fairly a novice on using MS Access and only have written simple if statements, if I could get a hand that would be awesome, thanks in advance !

**EDIT**: This is being used for a query to make a table inside MS Access, I am inputting the if statement in the 'Field' on the query design tab.

I have a table with a department code say '`12345`' and I have another table which has the correct department codes say '`12`', so I want to see if '`12345`' contains '`12`' then display the '`12`'

Comment: Where are you wanting to do this?  In a query?  Form? Report? Macro?

Comment: I edited the main post let me know if it isn't clear

Comment: the table where the department list is, is called DepartmentLookup, it has ID, Department Code, and Department name Fields. The second table is where all the information is, it is called MainIndex and it contains a field called Department, there is a department on this table that has code 400873, and on the department table only the first number or first two numbers matter, so If the second table contains the string code from the first table it should return the name for that department, so the third field in the Department table...

Comment: Judging by your edit, you would just need a wild card in a SQL statement, or an  [IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

Comment: I don't know how to check if a string contains another string, I do know how to make simple iif statements, can you give me an example ?

Comment: @TlbPython Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894539/reformatting-a-phone-number-in-access/26894847#26894847) ..  You can use `Left()`, `Right()`, and `Mid()` function to pull strings from other strings, which you can use in an `IIF`. Let me know if you need more info or another example